# box model issue with thin images in doctype html?

Tags: html, doctype, css

has anyone had any experience with thin images in the html box model?

ie
this code is killing me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<img src="myimage1.jpg" border="1" /></div>
<img src="myimage2.jpg.jpg" border="1" />
</body>
</html>
where both images are like 6px height and 960px wide
```

in a standard box model ie:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<img src="myimage1.jpg" border="1" /></div>
<img src="myimage2.jpg.jpg" border="1" />
</body>
</html>
```

this works as expected

can someone tell me how to make number 1 work like number two

Comment: Can you correct your code? You're closing a div you have never opened...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess what you are encountering.

```
<img src="myimage1.jpg" border="1" /></div>
```

What is happening -

Modern browsers/parsers, especially picky ones like Chrome will try to repair your code instead of ignoring the /div to make it semantic. If you are using developer tools, right click to inspect the element and you may notice that the browser has added a `<div></div>`

This is defined by the html5 `<!DOCTPE html>` which will make sure the browser forces it into a more strict mode rather than a quirks mode

Also 
changing the css for the image in the strict mode `display:block;` or `vertical-align:bottom;` will give you something similar to the quirks version

Answer (score 1):

Your second example, the "standard model" as you call it, is an incorrect one. It is "quirks mode" where no modern web page should ever be. A doctype, such as the one you show, is required of all new web pages to force standards mode. It is your first example, the one you are having problems with, that is showing you the correct box model and you should be following that.

Of course, this assumes you remove the mentioned stray ending div tag.

But you are obviously not showing us all the markup and something more is going on here that we can't help with without seeing it.